# Understanding $du \, dv$ or $(du)^2$ being dropped in Itô calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I will phrase my question in terms of a concrete example, which involves the proof presented for [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), where one is interested in solving the following PDE:

\begin{gather}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -V(x,t) u(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0, \end{gather}

defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in [0, T]$, subject to the terminal condition

\begin{gather}
u(x,T)=\psi(x), 
\end{gather}

where $\mu, \sigma, \psi, V, f$ are known functions, $T$ is a parameter and $ u:\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the unknown. [The proof about the form of the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula#Proof) starts as follows:

> Let $u(x, t)$ be the solution to the above partial differential
> equation.  Applying [the product rule for Ito's processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Product_Rule_for_It%C3%B4_processes) to the
> process:
>
> \begin{gather} Y(s) = e^{-\int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau} u(X_s,s)+
> > \int_t^s e^{-\int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}f(X_r,r) \,
> > dr\end{gather}
>
> one gets
>
> \begin{align} dY = {} & d\left(e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\,
> > d\tau}\right) u(X_s,s) + e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\,
> > d\tau}\,du(X_s,s) \\[6pt] & {} + d\left(e^{-  \int_t^s
> > V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\right)du(X_s,s) + d\left(\int_t^s e^{- 
> > \int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}  f(X_r,r) \, dr\right) \end{align}
>
> Since :\begin{gather}d\left(e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\,
> > d\tau}\right) =-V(X_s,s) e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}
> > \,ds,\end{gather}  the **third term is $O(dt \, du)$ and can be
> dropped.**

My question is mathematically (aka rigorously) what does it mean to just drop $O(dt \, du)$?? [I know the question has been raised before for this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590157/proof-of-feynman-kac-formula), but it seems OP there was convinced with yet another convergence argument, but my question is about the equality that is not based on asymptotic arguments. I assume in a rigorous sense $dt$ is a differential form. Can somebody in that language explain why such a cancellation takes place?

Comment: It's unfortunate that you are not getting answers. Try adding one tag such as "stochastic processes", maybe removing "derivatives" or "differential geometry". You want to attract the attention of people with a good grasp of Ito's formula, rather than calculus or PDE. As far as I understand, your question is a standard one in the theory of stochastic processes, and I even vaguely remember it being answered in the lecture notes on SDE of Craig Evans. I think he made a book out of them.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you so much for the constructive feedback and extensive comment. maybe I'll look into the course material of Evans. unfortunately i stopped studying math heavily after getting my bachelor in it. so your comment is especially helpful. hopefully the current formulation helps it getting attention

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to clarify what those differentials mean. If you are given the SDE $$dX_t = \mu(t,X_t) dt + \sigma(t,X_t) dB_t$$
where $B$ is a Brownian motion, then this is just shorthand for $$X_t - X_0 = \int_0^t \mu(s,X_s) ds + \int_0^t\sigma(s,X_s) dB_s$$
In this integral equation, the first integral is a pathwise Riemann integral and the second integral is an Itô integral. In particular, the differentials in this context have no intrinsic meaning.

Second: the reason why you can treat $du \, dv = (du)^2 = 0$ and $(dW_t)^2 = dt$ is because these formal products make Itô's formula work. In the proof of Itô's formula, these play the role of covariation, so that in particular:

$$\int_0^t (du)^2 = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i \in \pi^n} (u_i- u_{i-1})^2 \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{i \in \pi^n} |u_i - u_{i-1}|  \sum_{i \in \pi^n} |u_i- u_{i-1}| = 0$$
And,
$$\int_0^t(dW_s)^2 = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i \in \pi^n} (W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}})^2 = t = \int_0^t ds$$
Where $\pi = (\pi^n)$ is a refining partition whose mesh vanishes as $n\to\infty$.